# How to run binary at Linux startup with sound?

Tags: sound, startup, c++, autostart, sdl

I have a C++ program where I use the SDL2_Mixer module (which is based on Pulsesink, I think) to output audio. I want to run it on startup, but it does not want to work out very well. I set my default audio output device, volume etc. at startup automatically and have tried different ways to run the binary.

First, I included it in the Linux startup applications app. Then, I created a script in /etc/init.d which should run the binary and gave execute permissions. In both ways, I didn't hear any sound, even after I programmed in a delay so it can be made sure that everything is loaded and set when the binary runs.

Here's my code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL_mixer.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

const char waveFileName[40] = "audio/startup_sound.wav";
Mix_Chunk* sample;

int main() {
    if (Mix_Init(MIX_INIT_FLAC | MIX_INIT_MP3 | MIX_INIT_OGG) < 0) {
        exit(-1);
    }
    memset(sample, 0, sizeof(Mix_Chunk*) * 2);
    if (Mix_OpenAudio(44100, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 1024) < 0) {
        exit(-1);
    }
    Mix_AllocateChannels(2);
    sample = Mix_LoadWAV(waveFileName);
    if (sample == NULL) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    Mix_Volume(0, MIX_MAX_VOLUME);
    Mix_PlayChannel(0, sample, 0);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(13));

    Mix_FreeChunk(sample);
    Mix_CloseAudio();
    Mix_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

I want to point out that when I run the program manually from the terminal, it works perfectly. Is there a way to execute it automatically on startup so the audio output works?
Thanks!

Comment: If you are running it from `/etc/init.d` then chances are your program is being run before the sound subsystem is even initialized. It should be configured so that it runs after the sound subsystem is already running.

Comment: @raj That's what I suspected, but I have no idea how to do that. Can you please link me some guide or give a short explanation?

Comment: I already included a "sleep_for(seconds(30))" at the beginning, but that didn't work out.

Comment: I guess you have to investigate how to configure dependencies between startup scripts/services. I've never done that.